# Why can't I connect to ssh using an address?

Tags: ssh, gpg-agent

I have configured gpg-agent to connect to ssh, but for some reason I cannot connect using the device address. In **~/.ssh/config** I added

```
Host openwrt
Hostname 192.168.1.1
User root
```

Now using `ssh openwrt` I can connect, but I cannot if I am using `ssh 192.168.1.1`. Here is a little debug

```
OpenSSH_8.6p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear
debug1: compat_banner: no match: dropbear
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.1:22 as 'user'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:8BU0dCiyV/HSOZyyThViiuLyIQtIyQIQC5d/slYYJts
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '192.168.1.1' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: (none) RSA SHA256:dGSaK9m1A06YkSEnnLYHt9eHb02JfMeBaKp34SuwPf8 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:NUxAd9IHzP1O4GoEUBED1RcPW06JusvfUVIJpLJK754
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: (none) RSA SHA256:dGSaK9m1A06YkSEnnLYHt9eHb02JfMeBaKp34SuwPf8 agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:NUxAd9IHzP1O4GoEUBED1RcPW06JusvfUVIJpLJK754
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@192.168.1.1: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Before that I could use both methods, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're using `ssh 192.168.1.1`, you will connect as whatever user you are currently logged in as.  As this user, you have no access to the remote system, which is clear from the log:

```
user@192.168.1.1: Permission denied (publickey).
```

To use the IP address, you should additionally specify the exact user you will connect as:

```bsh
ssh root@192.168.1.1
```

Alternatively, make sure that there is an entry for `192.168.1.1` in your SSH configuration:

```
Host openwrt 192.168.1.1
    HostName 192.168.1.1
    User root
```

The way I've written the above configuration entry makes two separate hosts share the same section.  You may also use wildcards in the `Host` strings (see `man ssh_config`, but that's not really useful for solving this particular problem though).

This would make `ssh 192.168.1.1` work exactly the same as `ssh openwrt` from the account that has that SSH configuration.

(I personally don't allow root logins over SSH on any of my systems, as a safety precaution.  Instead, I would log in as a non-privileged user and then use `sudo` or some equivalent tool to access privileged operations.)